# How to generate boost uuid from string at compile time

Tags: c++, boost, uuid, boost-uuid

is there a way to generate a boost uuid from a string like 988A00C4-79F3-46f9-98CD-D5AD4AA2A0FE at compile time?

Comment: Why do you need this at compile time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because there is no processing of string literals at compile time in C++.

Depending on what you need and where you get the string from, you could use a pre-build-step that directly puts it into some aggregate initializer form or something that you can process at compile time (i.e. compile-time lists of characters).